# Recommended Go project structure and build system for project with static assets that require compilation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, go

I'm making a server in Go for a web app.  The app consists of Go code which will act as an http server and a websocket server for the app.  It will also include static assets to be served by the Go code, such as html/css/javascript/images/etc.  I plan to use [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) or equivalent to package the final static assets.  The desired form of deployment is a single binary executable with all static assets bundled in.

However, the javascript assets are to be built and organized in such a way that they will require a compilation step before they can be packaged into Go source for inclusion into the compiled binary.  This will be accomplished with npm scripts/webpack/gulp/equivalent.

I have read the official Go documentation about the [recommended project structure](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), but it doesn't seem to address my kind of use case.

I don't know if the frontend code and backend code should live in the same git repo or separate ones.  I don't know what build process should handle running the javascript compilation process, the go-bindata process, and the `go build` process.  Is there a recommended way to manage this type of project or perhaps some examples of similar successful projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I do:

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/myname/myproject:
-main.go //handlers and code
-static.go //generated
-static
    -js
      -foo.js
    -html
    -css
    -img
```

I use [github.com/mjibson/esc](http://github.com/mjibson/esc) to convert everything in `static` to a virtual filesystem in static.go. If there are additional tasks to generate css/js (I run typescript compiler), those can be run before you embed the assets.

All of this gets wired up to `go generate` with comments:

```
//go:generate sass or tsc or grunt or whatever
//go:generate esc -o static.go static
```

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a repository handy that demonstrates this, would you?

Comment: A really simple example: https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/tree/master/cmd/snmpTester. Up the tree in that repo is the cmd/bosun package which is quite a bit more complicated.